# ¿Cómo usar una MySql en un programa de Java?

Tags: java

¿como podría conectar mi programa a una base de datos MySql? Soy nuevo en Java, Gracias

Comment: Una respuesta a esta pregunta puede ser demasiado amplia y subjetiva. Te recomiendo que busques en internet tutoriales sobre como hacer la conexión [Link de interés](https://www.google.cl/search?q=conectar+java+mysql) Cuando tengas alguna pregunta mas concreta , problema, error o situación particular ten toda la libertad de compartirla aquí, mientras tanto, es bastante probable que esta pregunta sea cerrada por ser demasiado amplia :(

Comment: He votado para que esta pregunta se deje abierta. 1º porque se trata de un usuario reciente en esSO, 2º porque es una pregunta que puede dar lugar a una respuesta interesante, rica que más de un usuario necesitará, 3º porque preguntas similares han tenido muy buena aceptación en enSO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database Ya comenté en el meta que cerrar este tipo de preguntas empobrecen el contenido de esSO: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1470/mi-pregunta-ha-sido-considerada-como-demasiado-amplia-y-corre-el-riesgo-de-ser-c

Answer (score 5):

Hay más de una manera de hacerlo. Te dejo instrucciones básicas de cómo hacerlo con JDBC.

Asumamos la configuración siguiente a modo de ejemplo:

- Nombre del servidor donde tienes instalada la base de datos `MySQL`: `servidor` (asumamos que el servicio MySQL corre en el port por defecto, que es 3306)
- Nombre de la base de datos a la que quieres conectarte: `db`
- Nombre de usuario para conectarte la base de datos: `user`
- Contraseña para conectarte a la base de datos: `pass`

Y digamos que tienes la tabla siguiente definida en tu base de datos `db`:

```sql
create table tbl (
  col1 varchar(50),
  col2 varchar(50)
);
```

Entonces, realmente, lo único que necesitas es bajar el driver JDBC para MySQL de [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) e incluirlo como librería en tu proyecto Java.

Con eso arreglado, el código muy básico siguiente te muestra un ejemplo de cómo conectarte a la base de datos y leer los datos de la tabla `tbl`:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class MySqlCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String usuario = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://servidor:3306/db";

        try (Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);
            PreparedStatement ps = conexion.prepareStatement("select * from tbl");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.printf(
                    "%s-%s%n",
                    rs.getString("col1"),
                    rs.getString("col2"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Por supuesto, te tocará modificar un poco el código según la configuración que tu tienes en realidad, pero eso no es difícil.

Es más, vale la pena mencionar que este código modelo te permite conectar a prácticamente cualquier tipo de base de datos. Los únicos ajustes necesarios son:

1. Necesitas bajar e incluir el driver JDBC apropiado para la base de datos que usas.
2. Necesitas modificar el valor para `url` para que sea apropiado para la base datos/driver JDBC que usas.

Pero aparte de esos 2 pequeños detalles, el resto del código funciona prácticamente igual.

Answer (score 3):

Como ya se ha comentado, existen varias formas de conectarse a una base de datos.

Una forma muy utilizada y recomendada es el uso de lo que se llama **Patrón Singleton**.

### ¿Qué es un patrón singleton?

Es un patrón diseñado para limitar la creación de objetos pertenecientes a una clase. El objetivo de este patrón es el de garantizar que una clase solo tenga una sola instancia y proporcionar un punto de acceso global a ella.

Este tipo de clases son habituales en temas como configurar parámetros generales de la aplicación ya que una vez instanciado el objeto los valores se mantienen y son compartidos  por toda la aplicación.

Para conseguir que una clase sea de tipo Singleton necesitamos básicamente tres cosas:

1. Que su **constructor sea privado**. De esa forma ningún programa será capaz de construir objetos de esta tipo.
2. Disponer de una **variable estatica privada** que almacene una referencia al objeto que vamos a crear a traves del constructor.
3. **Un método estático publico** que se encarga de instanciar el objeto la primera vez y almacenarlo en la variable estática.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### ¿Cuándo usar patrones singleton y cuándo no usarlos?

En general, usaremos este patrón cuando:
- Debe haber exactamente una instancia de una clase y deba ser accesible a los clientes desde un punto de acceso conocido.
- Se requiere de un acceso estandarizado y conocido públicamente.

Sus usos más comunes son clases que representan **objetos unívocos**. Por ejemplo, si hay un servidor que necesita ser representado mediante un objeto, este debería ser único, es decir, debería existir una sola instancia y el resto de las clases deberían de comunicarse con el mismo servidor. Una base de datos específica también es única, o un Calendario determinado, una clase que representa un hospital determinado, una universidad determinada, etc.

En cambio, no lo usaremos cuando una clase está representando a un objeto que no es único. Por ejemplo, la clase Persona no debería ser Singleton, ya que representa a una persona real y cada persona tiene su propio nombre, edad, domicilio, DNI, fecha de nacimiento, etc.

### Clase de ejemplo implementando el patrón singleton

Este ejemplo está tomando de la [documentación de Java](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-918906). En el enlace hay más cosas interesantes sobre la implementación singleton. Pero... está en inglés :( He traducido los comentarios de la clase, que explican con claridad los puntos importantes de la misma.

```
    public class DbSingleton {
    private static String db_url;
    private static String db_port;
    private static String db_name;
    private static String db_user;
    private static String db_password;
    private static Statement connection;

    private DbSingleton() {
/* 
       *Parámetros por defecto de la base de datos 
*/
        db_url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost";
        db_port = "3306";
        db_name = "mysql";
        db_user = "root";
        db_password = "admin";
/* Creación de una instancia del estado de la conexión*/
        connection = setConnection();
    }
/* Método privado encargado de setear la conexión*/
    private static Statement setConnection() {
        try {
            String url = "" + db_url + ":" + db_port + "/" + db_name + "";
            java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, db_user, db_password);

            //Creación del objeto Estado (Statement)
            java.sql.Statement state = conn.createStatement();
            return (Statement) state;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbSingleton.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

/* Clase Privada interna responsable de instanciar la instancia única del singleton */
    private static class DbSingletonManagerHolder {
        private final static DbSingleton instance = new DbSingleton();
    }

    /**
     * @return
Método público, el cual es el único autorizado a devolver una instancia del singleton (aquí la instancia es la conexión a la base de datos). 
     */
    public static DbSingleton getInstance() {
        try {
            return DbSingletonManagerHolder.instance;
        } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError ex) {

        }
        return null;
    }
    public static Statement getStatement() {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

### Uso de la clase singleton en cualquier parte del programa

Teniendo nuestra clase singleton para conectar a la base de datos, nos olvidamos de todo y sólo obtenemos una instancia de conexión y le enviamos la consulta que querramos.

Por ejemplo:

```
/* Creación de una instancia de la conexión */
DbSingleton single = DbSingleton.getInstance();
Statement state = DbSingleton.getStatement();

/* Enviar una consulta a la base de datos */
String sqlString = "SELECT id, nombre, apellidos FROM personas" ;
ResultSet result = state.executeQuery(sqlString);
```

**Nota:**
Nuestra clase singleton se puede mejorar, dependiendo del alcance de nuestra aplicación, o se puede completar con una clase que maneje por ejemplo las consultas SQL que enviamos a la misma. En mi caso particular, prefiero tener aparte todas mis consultas y/o un constructor de consultas (query builder) en el caso de consultas dinámicas con parámetros del tipo `WHERE` u otros, para evitar el ir repitiendo código por todos lados y porque a la hora de modificar algo es más fácil tener en un sólo lugar todo aquello que se repite.

Aunque se trate de una aplicación sencilla, yo usaría desde el principio este tipo de implementaciones, por adquirir buenas prácticas de programación y porque una aplicación que empieza siendo pequeña, podría crecer con el tiempo... nadie sabe.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54798/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-como-usar-una-mysql-en-un-programa-de-java).

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaré probando con las opciones que me recomendaron :)

Comment: @SinXeros De nada. En todo caso tener una clase de conexión única a la que puedas llamar desde cualquier parte permitirá que tu programa quede más organizado y que sea más fácil de mantener en caso de futuros cambios. Tener conexiones por todas partes complicaría más cualquier modificación futura. Saludos.